# What were the earliest images uploaded on the internet before the web?

Tags: internet

What's the earliest images uploaded on the internet before the protocol the web existed? People believed the Cernettes image was the first image on the internet when it's actually the first image on the web in 1992, not the internet itself.

Comment: Does "images" mean "digital photographs" or "any digital graphics"? With a nominal start date for the internet of 1983-01-01 there were plenty of graphics at the time, so arguably any application transmitted over the beginning internet could have contained images (e.g., in a game) but not much in the way of "digital photographs".

Comment: Somehow this question doesn't make any sense as written . For example what is _"uploaded on the internet"_ supposed to mean, or what. Uploaded to where? Transferred using any network? Transferred by any other means? Or what is the 'protocol' mentioned? A network protocol, or some user level one? If yes, which one? What is 'the web' supposed to mark here? What about images that were on a future 'web' server even before the first was started? Images such being created on that machine?

Comment: I was referring to images as in digital graphics such as ASCII art and digital art, not digital photograph, although there are graphics in the internet at that time, there weren't any photographs due to technical limitations.

Comment: I don't know who uploaded it first, or even when, but the earliest image uploaded on the internet was this [ascii art](https://a.1stdibscdn.com/unknown-prints-works-on-paper-ascii-mona-lisa-for-sale/a_14422/a_81616921621962149537/ascii_full_master.jpg?width=768) for sure.

Comment: The earliest images uploaded on the internet was ASCII art and you're right.

Comment: @davidbak - are we sure it was 'uploaded to' and was not just 'already on' the internet?  After all, it apparently existed before the internet  :-)

Comment: Not cats. Porn ;)

Comment: @dave - it definitely _did_ exist before the internet.  I saw it when I was in high school in the early 70s, printed on standard greenbar from a mainframe.  (Amazing, given what mainframe usage costs were ... still didn't stop people from fooling around on them ...). Anyway, my comment was a joke, as you know ...

Comment: @davidbak that would be EDCDIC-art… :D

Comment: @RonJohn - oh, oh! You're quite right!

Comment: I should’ve written EBCDIC.

Answer (score 11):

A crop of the November 1972 issue of Playboy centerfold model Lena Forsén, AKA  [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna), used as a standard test image for image processing, as well as data compression, has been circulating in the computer graphics circles since 1973. First on ARPANET and USENET, of course.

Comment: :)) Good example to render the whole question pointless. I like it.